# Disable or change global keyboard shortcut of specific application

Tags: shortcut-keys, 21.10, evernote

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10. When the Evernote application is running, it intercepts some shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) when the Evernote window is not active. Because of this, these shortcuts are not working in another application (Intellij IDEA), when its window is active.

- I can't find how can change/disable these shortcuts in Evernote config.
- I can't find these shortcuts in Settings → *Keyboard* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*.
- I can't find these shortcuts in `dconf-settings`.

How can one disable/change these global shortcuts of Evernote?